# How to get ip address of a user in laravel 4.2

Tags: laravel-4

I am using

```
$log['ip_address'] = Request::getClientIp();
```

to get the client ip address but i am not getting the ip address using this.

Is there any other method available to get the user ip address?

Answer (score 1):

In Laravel 4.2 Request::ip() or Request::ips() will get the IP address of the request.